# Telegram session ping

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, telegram

I'm coding a custom telegram client, I'm using an async socket in order to receive the updates from the telegram server. The problem is that after a while seems that the connection is closed by the server, and my socket goes crazy starting to receive null bytes inside the ReceiveCallback.

Is a ping ( https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/service_messages#ping-messages-ping-pong ) to telegram servers necessary in order to solve this problem? The documentation doesn't say that it is mandatory, but I can't figure out the reason of this behavior.